# Text based health If object hit then -20 Actions Script 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am create a little game just to get more experience in Action Script 3.0.
What I want is:

If you shoot. And the bullet hits. Than the text above should -20..
Say It has 100(health). And we hit. It will display 80. Second hit 60 etc.

This is what I am having but it does not seem to work out.

```
 var a;
 var b;

 a = 100;
 b = 20;

Health.text = a

//-------- This above part works.

//After adding the part under here. The whole 'Game' doesnt work.

if (kogel.hitTestObject(baws)) //Kogel=bullet. Baws=target

        {
            Health.text = -b
        }
```

This is the whole code;
    $

```
var geweer;  //poppetje in de instance name voor je object die je wilt bewegen.
var ster:Star;
var omhoog;
var omlaag;
var a;
var b;

a = 100;
b = 20;

Health.text = a

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,beweeg);
function beweeg(event:KeyboardEvent)


    { 
        switch(event.keyCode)
        {
            case 38:
            geweer.y = geweer.y -10;
            //kogel.y = kogel.y -10;
            break;

            case 40:
            geweer.y = geweer.y +10;
            //kogel.y = kogel.y +10;
            break;

            case 32:
            kogel = new Star();
            addChild(kogel);
            kogel.y = geweer.y
            kogel.x = geweer.x

        }

            }

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
function enterFrameHandler(event:Event)

{

kogel.x = kogel.x + 5

    }


if (kogel.hitTestObject(baws))
        {
            Health.text = -b
        }
```

Thanks,

Levi

Comment: you're in way over your head here. You don't understand the basic basics of variables (you don't understand to look at what variables hold, not their names). Step back a bit, down to basics. Find 2 3 general programming tutorials on the net and start going through their variable sections... over and over again... after that you can fix the reference error by correctly naming the textfield and using that same name in code (name is set in Properties panel, "Instance Name"). Learn to use google to research compiler errors ("as3 Error #1065").

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work better

```
if (kogel.hitTestObject(baws)) //Kogel=bullet. Baws=target

  {
    a -= b;
    Health.text = a;
  }
```

Comment: Erhm.. Well. After the bullet hits the object. It should count -20.

Comment: You are not really clarifying - should it BE -20 or should it lose 20 ?

Comment: Then you AT LEAST need to make the change I suggested

Comment: I can make the change. But the problem is I cant make the change after hitting the object.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: I am no AS 3.0 coder but many imperative languages use
>   similar assignment principles.

It looks like you're just assigning to the text to -20. What you should do is

```
Health.text = Health.text - b
```

or

```
Health.text -= b
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error: Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable TLFTextField is not defined.

Comment: Okay, so the text is an actual text string, and not a number that can be directly changed. By the looks of your error, though, the problem does not have to do with calculating health at all, but related to how the text is loaded.

Comment: Do you have any idea how this is solved? Or how to add a number that can be directly displayed?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no Actionsript wiz, but someone that is should be able to. Post that whole error message in your question, then it could be answered more easily.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for attempting to help out, I just want to point out you are subtracting from a string in this example (String ->Number is a disallowed implicit coercion)... the correct would be a -= b; and then Health.text = a; (if Health was the correct instance name, it probably isn't)

Comment: Hello.. I've got a TLF textfield named Health. I've tried your code. a-=b; Health.text=a. It keeps giving me the same error. On the internet i found it has something to do with public classes. (that should fix it.) But i am not using a class.. Thank you for trying to help me out.